# Playing sound on silent mode when phone is on stand-by

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Is it possible to play a sound on an iPhone with push notification while the phone is on silent mode and stand-by? On either React Native or Swift.

Comment: no possible in iOS

Comment: Of course not...

Comment: Alright, thank you I thought so but I just wanted to make sure.